# JNA 2 Dimensional Arrays

Tags: jna

JNA 2 Dimensional Arrays

My C function is

```
    void func(void** bufs, int numBufs);
```

Tye C-code is expecting an array of pointers to arrays of bytes. `func()` knows the length of each of the byte arrays and fills them with data.

What is the JNA signature for this?

I have wrestled with this seemingly simple problem for two days and not cracked it.

On the Java side I have `DirectBuffer bufs[]` and the intention is for the C function to populate `bufs[]` with data.

I had expected that I could declare the JNA signature as

```
    public static native boolean func(Pointer[] bufs, int numBufs);
```

and then construct a Java array of Pointers each Pointer being `new Pointer(db.address());`

But whilst I can construct the java array of Pointers I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class [Lcom.sun.jna.Pointer; is not a supported argument type (in method func in class SomeLib)
```

I have experimented at length and am getting nowhere. I have looked at all the JNA examples on StackOver flow, but none quite fit.

I am using using JNA via Maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Unfortunately the mapping of non-primitive arrays to C only works one way... you can map retrieved memory to the Java array, but not send a Java array to C (except for primitives).

The reason for this restriction is that in C, arrays are contiguous blocks of memory.  To access the second element of an array, you just offset by a number of bytes equal to the size of the first element. But the argument you pass to a C function is simply a pointer to the beginning of the array.

So your mapping of `func()` should use a `Pointer` for the array argument.

You didn't describe how you constructed your `Pointer[]` array, but allocating each with a `new Pointer()` call will produce pointers scattered across the native memory rather than contiguous.

There are basically two approaches to ensuring you have contiguous memory, depending on the level of abstraction you want.

One low-level approach is to create a `Memory` object, allocating enough room for your `Pointer` array (probably `new Memory(Native.POINTER_SIZE * numBufs)`) and then using `setPointer()` with the appropriate multiple of `Native.POINTER_SIZE` offset to map your array to the `Memory` object.  Then pass the `Memory` object to the C function.

A higher level approach is to wrap the Pointer in a JNA `Structure`, using the `Structure.toArray()` method to do that contiguous array allocation for you.  So you could have this:

```
public class Foo extends Structure {
    public Pointer bar; 
}
```

And then create the array:

```
Foo[] array = (Foo[]) new Foo().toArray(numBufs);
```

At this point you have a (contiguous) array of native memory mapped to JNA's `Pointer` type.  Now you just need to assign these Pointers-to-pointers to the pointers attached to your data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numBufs; i++) {
    // Assign Pointer to corresponding DirectBuffer
    array[i].bar = bufs[i];
}
```

Then you should be able to pass the Array to C by passing the first element's pointer:

```
func(array[0].bar, numBufs);
// or equivalently
func(array[0].getPointer(), numBufs);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent explanation and detailed code. Will give it a try right now.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked a treat! I went with the low level version on my first attempt but will explore the extending Structure version to see which looks more elegant.

I did find that Pointer.SIZE does not exist and am currently used a constant  of 8 which is assumes a 64 bit platform, so that may be reason enough to use the the alternative approach you illustrate. 

So once again many thanks.

It does seem to me that this surely must be a very common case scenario for JNA users. Is there any way this can be added to the JNA site as an example?

Comment: Oops, [Pointer.SIZE](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#SIZE) was in version 4.x but was replaced in 5.x by [Native.POINTER_SIZE](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.3.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#POINTER_SIZE) to prevent a class loading deadlock, when JNA is initialized from multiple threads.

Comment: As for adding to the JNA site, I'd suggest posting your question on the JNA mailing list and asking if the current docs handle it.  It's entirely possible there's a better solution than the one(s) I've posted.

Comment: My buffers are DirectBuffers created by `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`

I assign the pointer by casting the `ByteBuffer` to `DirectBuffer` so I can get 
```
   DirectBuffer db = (DirectBuffer) myBuffer;
   ptr.setPointer(i * Native.POINTER_SIZE, new Pointer(db.address()));
```

But I now note that sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer is an internal proprietary API. Is there a way to avoid using the internal proprietary API for this?

Comment: Same answer. :)  Use `Memory` to allocate the bytes and have a pointer to it, or wrap a `Structure.ByReference` around a `byte[]`.   There may be better answers.